# Creating a table with a sequence of values without inserting each one manually

Tags: sql, postgresql

I (think I) want to create a view or temporary table that contains a sequence. 
The purpose of this table is simply to provide values needed to make a panel data set.
What I would like to do is create this sequence programmatically, using every value between two periods like 0 and 365, with gaps of 7 (say to make a weekly panel).
Here is how it can be done "manually", inserting each of the cutoff days by hand.

```
create table time_periods (day_cutoff int); 
insert into time_periods values (7); 
insert into time_periods values (14); 
insert into time_periods values (28); 
insert into time_periods values (35); 
insert into time_periods values (42);
```

This table would then be used as so (doing a full cartesian join on an underling table of `billing_records` that contains ad hoc instances of when a billing was made.

```
select 
buyer
, seller
, day_cutoff
, sum(case when billing_day < day_cutoff 
      then amount 
      else 0.0 end) as cumulative_spend
from time_periods 
left join billing_records 
on 1 = 1 
group by buyer, seller, day_cutoff
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `generate_series`:

```
select *
from generate_series(7, 42, 7);
```

It is documented [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-srf.html).

Here is one way to write your query:

```
select buyer, seller, day_cutoff,
       sum(case when br.billing_day < day_cutoff then amount else 0.0 end) as cumulative_spend
from billing_records br cross join
     generate_series(7, 42, 7) as day_cutoff
group by buyer, seller, day_cutoff ;
```